# How to create and to merge a 2D transparent barcode on top of a JPG image in PHP?

Tags: php, barcode

Could you please see the below code and let me know how to write the `$png` on top of the `$jpg` image? The code shows the bacode image in the browser, but it does not save it and merge it with `$jpg` image. thanks for taking time and help.

```
        $jpg= imagejpeg($image, '/applications/AMPPS/www/files/final-image-2.jpg');

        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php');


        // set the barcode content and type
        $barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode('Hello-this-is-a-test', 'DATAMATRIX');

        // output the barcode as PNG image
        $barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(6, 6, array(0,0,0));
       // the code stops to work from here
        $png= imagepng($barcodeobj, '/applications/AMPPS/www/certificates/barcode.jpg');
        imagecopymerge($png, $jpg, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($png);
```

Comment: You need to do some research first. Attempt to solve it on your own. When you're stuck, come back and show your attempt and ask for help

Comment: No. That's not how this site works. We don't give you code on demand.

Comment: @Duniyadnd, thanks for your comment. could you please see the above code and let me know how to write the generated barcode in the browser on top of the `$jpg` image and then save the image into a new file?

Comment: @Apiah - sorry can't help unless you state an actual issue in your code. You're asking to solve the entire process for you and this is a little trivial. I only went with the assumption that a pdf output was ok because you never specified what the output format should be.